# SpringWithDamping for CALayer animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, calayer

After playing around a lot with the `UIView` dynamic animations introduced in iOS 7, most notably:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations: completion:];
```

I was wondering if there is an equivalent to 'SpringWithDamping/Velocity' method that can be accessed directly when creating a `CALayer` animation? I.e. either through `CATransaction`, `CABasicAnimation` or otherwise...

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer below - there's a new class to do that in iOS9

Answer (score 77, accepted):

in **iOS9** Apple finally made the `CASpringAnimation` class public.

You can use it like that:

```
let spring = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
spring.damping = 5
spring.fromValue = myLayer.position.x
spring.toValue = myLayer.position.x + 100.0
spring.duration = spring.settlingDuration
myLayer.addAnimation(spring, forKey: nil)
```

Notice that you cannot set the animation duration - you need to ask the `CASpringAnimation` class for the `settlingDuration` (e.g. "How much time is going to take for the spring system to settle down") and then set it as the duration of your animation.

Check the header files for `CASpringAnimation` - it exposes a number of spring system variables you can adjust - stiffness, mass, etc.

Comment: "Notice that you cannot set the animation duration" – you actually can set it to any value, but if it's too short it may abruptly stop before settling so if you don't want to do the guess work yourself `settlingDuration` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

There is (and have been for a while) a private class called [`CASpringAnimation`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/CASpringAnimation.h) that I'm pretty sure is being used behind it all (but I haven't verified it). Unfortunately, it is still private.

Comment: Thanks @David, this is what I found also, but as it is private I don't want to use it in deployment. — Do you happen to have any personal experience in any other libraries/classes that achieve the same effect? Thanks!

Comment: @Rorz No, I don't have any experience with other libraries. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

As David said, `CASpringAnimation` is private (for now?), but I recently came across `RBBSpringAnimation` from the [RBBAnimation](https://github.com/robb/RBBAnimation) project.

I can definitely recommend this, it was very easy to drop in as a replacement for my existing CABasicAnimation.

Comment: Agreed, using `RBBSpringAnimation` is an accurate replacement for CASpringAnimation. Useful if you are trying to support iOS 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class to create `CASpringAnimation` instance. It works in a pretty simple way:

By creating a spring animation from UIKit API, it arrests the created `CASpringAnimation` instance from the view's layer, copies it and returns it.

But I don't know if it is App Store safe that to create `CASpringAnimation` in this way.

```
import UIKit

private let SharedCASpringAnimationFactory = CASpringAnimationFactory()

public class CASpringAnimationFactory {
    private var dummyView: UIView

    private init() {
        dummyView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    }

    private class var shared: CASpringAnimationFactory {
        return SharedCASpringAnimationFactory
    }


     public class func animation(#keyPath: String, dumping: CGFloat, initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat) -> CABasicAnimation {
        let duration = CATransaction.animationDuration()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: dumping, initialSpringVelocity: initialSpringVelocity, options: nil,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                CASpringAnimationFactory.shared.dummyView.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
            }, completion: nil)

        let dummyLayer = CASpringAnimationFactory.shared.dummyView.layer

        let animations = dummyLayer.animationKeys().map {dummyLayer.animationForKey($0 as String) as CAAnimation}

        let arrestedAnimation = animations.first!.copy() as CABasicAnimation
        arrestedAnimation.keyPath = keyPath
        arrestedAnimation.fromValue = nil
        arrestedAnimation.toValue = nil

        dummyLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        shared.dummyView.bounds = CGRect.zeroRect

        return arrestedAnimation
    }
}
```